# IE8 navbar renders with the toggle showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am using the Bootstrap 3 `navbar` like this in my app:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"><span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">mapERP</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-pills" id="navbarCollapse">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 pull-left">
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search" id="search-form">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="geo-search" id="geo-search">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div> 
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right clearfix">
        <li><p class="navbar-text" id="userName"style="display:none;"></a></li>
        <li><img class="img-responsive img-circle" id="userImg" src="" style="display:none;"></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="authorize-button">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>           
  </div>    
 </nav>
```

I am using this conditional comment for IE like this:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
     <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Inside conditional comment");
            window.isIE=true;
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/lib/respond.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/lib/json2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/lib/Object.keys-polyfill.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

I find that `respond.min.js` loads as suggested in other answers but the `navbar-toggle` is still shows up and all the `navbar-nav` items are oversized.

[Screenshot of the way it should look in desktop mode](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hlgjy0vl7d10wex/Screenshot%202014-09-15%2007.11.13.png?dl=0)

[Screenshot of the way it IE8 renders it](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fr5zv6ifj1owhva/Screenshot%202014-09-15%2007.13.18.png?dl=0)

## EDIT:

As suggested in the comments,I have downloaded and added `respond.min.js` to the page using a relative path,this html was copied from IE8:

```
  <SCRIPT src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></SCRIPT>
  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries --><!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
            alert("Inside conditional comment");
            window.isIE=true;
   </SCRIPT>
   <SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="http://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js">   
   </SCRIPT>
   <SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="scripts/lib/respond.min.js"></SCRIPT>
   <SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="scripts/lib/json2.js"></SCRIPT>
   <SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="scripts/lib/Object.keys-polyfill.js"></SCRIPT>
   <LINK rel=stylesheet href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Where is your css located. If it's not a relative path, respond.js won't work

Comment: @Christina I was using it from a CDN but now I have moved it to a relative path.

Comment: Are you serving the page via a webserver, or viewing the file locally?

Comment: @TiesonT. I am accessing it using `localhost` via a web server.

Comment: "Reference the respond.min.js script (1kb min/gzipped) after all of your CSS " - perhaps you need to move the bootstrap CSS link before the respond.js script?

Comment: @TiesonT. I moved it to the bottom of `head` which was after I was done loading all the CSS and it works.[Here is my code](http://pastebin.com/kPRWYsWX)